# Hyperlink columns in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a folder which has different types of files like doc, xls, ppt etc. My gridview displays, ID, filename and type. I want to make the filename column as hyperlink. Is it possible the hyperlink column acts as both hyperlink + selected index? What i mean to say is, when I click on filename it should not take me to another page, but opens the file which I click on? I used a commandfield in gridview with text as view, which displays all indexes of that column as view. But Now I dont want like that. Instead I want hyperlink field acting as that commandfield. Is it possible?

What exactly I want is, If the gridview looks like this
If the gridview shows as

Id      Filename            Type

---

1        cell                   doc

2        wood                 xls

3        tiger                 ppt

I want to display cell, wood and tiger as hyperlinks and they should not take me to another page, instead, they should open the files from the folder

Answer (score 1):

You could create a custom handler (.ashx) file and set the response header info accordingly. That should take care of being redirected to another page.

**1) Register a generic HttpHandler to handle downloads** *(Add > New Item > Generic Handler):*

Downloads.ashx.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Web;

namespace FileDownloads
{
    public class Downloads : IHttpHandler
    {
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            var file = context.Request.QueryString["f"];

            // Assuming all downloadable files are in a folder called "downloads"
            // located at the root of your website/application...
            var path = context.Server.MapPath(
                string.Format("~/downloads/{0}", file)
            );

            var response = context.Response;
            response.ClearContent();
            response.Clear();
            response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition",
                string.Format("attachment; filename={0};", file)
            );
            response.WriteFile(path);
            response.Flush();
            response.End();
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get { return false; }
        }
    }
}
```

**2) Wire-up your GridView like this:**

defalut.aspx:

```
<asp:gridview id="downloadsGridView" runat="server" autogeneratecolumns="false">
    <columns>
        <asp:hyperlinkfield headertext="File Name"
          datatextfield="Name"
          datanavigateurlfields="Name"
          datanavigateurlformatstring="~/Downloads.ashx?f={0}" />
    </columns>
</asp:gridview>
```

default.aspx.cs:

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.IO;

namespace FileDownloads
{
    public partial class _default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsPostBack) return;

            var directory = Server.MapPath("~/downloads/");
            var filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(directory);

            downloadsGridView.DataSource = filePaths.Select(x => new DLFile
            {
                Name = x.Split('\\').Last()
            });
            downloadsGridView.DataBind();
        }

        public class DLFile
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously, you will need to tweak the above example to suit your specific requirements. Downloading files via the above method is a perfect example of when you **should use a Generic HttpHandler.**

Comment: What exactly I want is, If the gridview looks like this
If the gridview shows as

    Id      Filename            Type
    
    ---------------------------------
    
    1        cell                   doc
    
    2        wood                 xls
    
    3        tiger                 ppt

I want to display cell, wood and tiger as hyperlinks and they should not take me to another page, instead, they should open the files from the folder

Comment: Yes, using the method i described in my answer will prevent users from being redirected to another page. Clicking the link will trigger a "Save as" dialog. I will post a more complete example in a little bit

Comment: @ErOx Hi Erox I am generating a grid-view dynamically, from a share point list. In SPlist I have an attachment where I should need to show that attachment or give a hyperlink to it. I have  a string ath which holds the attachment URL (Ex http: //sk123/Lists/CapabilityTableSales/attachments/1/Dashboard Solutions.pptx). Though I used the hyperlink field it is giving an error like "Column Mismatch", how can I get it done ? I will post the URL for my question soon !!